# Autocomplete on mobile browsers for username fields

Tags: mobile, autocomplete

I'm looking for useful advice on whether autocomplete should be disabled or not on mobile browsers specifically for inputs in a username field.

I already have: `<input type="email" name="signin-email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">`

What is the current support for autocompleting email addresses and usernames?

Comment: Especially annoying is when the username is my full email address, and it specifically won't remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is there any specific reason to disable autocomplete?**

if not,  disabling that would add a 'little' dislike to your site.

Username should be enabled for autocompletion,  Which is more true for mobile browsing, where typing is still quite challenging except the young users.

- Consider the major age category of your users. If that's over 25,  typing on mobile is quite cumbersome. Add to that, someone may be using very small-display mobile.
- Usually, email-address is quite a long "word" to type in, where the mobile keyboard **can't** help with "auto-predict".
- A mobile is much more personal than a PC, so is its browser. So, filling up a username field wrongfully will be very rare.

Comment: I think your question simply addresses this. There isn't a specific reason to disable it, so it's better to keep it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I advise keeping autocomplete unless you/your users would be concerned about it for security reasons. In general, autocomplete is convenient for users so they don't need to waste time typing their info (especially on mobile).